# Power Query Function - Optional Arguments - Token Literal Expected

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, powerquery

I am trying to create a function in powerquery that will accept optional arguments.  The purpose of the function is to establish a common directory that will be used for text imports in other queries within the workbook.  Typically for our models, we have a Parent Directory that has the following structure:

```
Financial_Ind_Ovr_Dashoards
    Data
        -Data_File_1.txt
        -Data_File_2.txt
        -Data_File_3.txt
    Models
        -Model1.xlsm
        -Model2.xlsm
```

Sometimes, though, either the Data or Models directory will be named or nested differently.

These parent directories are constantly moved from place to place while keeping the structure.  Due to this, I am trying to get a relative file path for our import queries.  With that being said, I am getting an error with my code:

```
let
    GET_DATA_PATH = (optional dir_nest_level as number, optional data_dir_path as text) =>

    //Handle Input
    cur_dir_nest_level = if dir_nest_level = null or dir_nest_level = "" then 1
                                                                         else dir_nest_level,

    data_dir_path_from_parent_dir = if data_dir_path = null or data_dir_path = "" then "Data\"
                                                                                  else data_dir_path,


    //Get Path
    full_path = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="WORKBOOK_PATH"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    separators = Text.PositionOf(full_path, "\", Occurrence.All),
    dir_count = List.Count(separators),
    sep_index = dir_count - 1 - cur_dir_nest_level,
    GET_DATA_PATH = Text.Start(full_path, separators{sep_index} + 1) & data_dir_path_from_parent_dir
 in
    GET_DATA_PATH
```

When writing this as a regular query (rather than function) I know that my logic after the //Get Path comment works fine.  After adding the logic to make this a function and handle the input, I keep getting the following error:

```
Expression.SyntaxError: Token Literal expected.
```

This error occurs on the first if statement where I am referencing the cur_dir_nest_level variable.  I'm not really familiar with power query functions so I'm sure I am doing something incorrect.  Any and all insght would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten the extra let you need:

```
let
    GET_DATA_PATH = (optional dir_nest_level as number, optional data_dir_path as text) =>
     let
        //Handle Input
    cur_dir_nest_level = if dir_nest_level = null or dir_nest_level = "" then 1
                                                                         else dir_nest_level,

    data_dir_path_from_parent_dir = if data_dir_path = null or data_dir_path = "" then "Data\"
                                                                                  else data_dir_path,


    //Get Path
    full_path = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="WORKBOOK_PATH"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    separators = Text.PositionOf(full_path, "\", Occurrence.All),
    dir_count = List.Count(separators),
    sep_index = dir_count - 1 - cur_dir_nest_level,
    GET_DATA_PATH = Text.Start(full_path, separators{sep_index} + 1) & data_dir_path_from_parent_dir
    in
        GET_DATA_PATH
in
    GET_DATA_PATH
```